# Intersection of graphs in NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx

I have 2 graphs and I would like to obtain a graph with their intersecting edges.
If we have for instance:

```
import networkx as nx

graph1 = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(100, 3)
graph2 = nx.watts_strogatz_graph(100, 4, 0.15)
nx.draw_networkx(graph1, with_labels=True)
nx.draw_networkx(graph2, with_labels=True)
```

How could I find their intersection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on how you define *intersection* really. If what you want is to keep all *intersecting* edges from both graphs, you can use [`nx.intersection`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.operators.binary.intersection.html), which as mentioned in the docs, keeps all edges that exist in both graphs. So say you have the following graphs:

```
graph1 = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(100, 3)
graph2 = nx.watts_strogatz_graph(100, 4, 0.15)
```

Which produce the following graphs:

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(graph1, scale=20, k=3/np.sqrt(graph1.order()))
nx.draw(graph1, pos=pos, with_labels=True, k=13.8, node_color='lightgreen', node_size=800)
```

[image]

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(graph2, scale=20, k=3/np.sqrt(graph2.order()))
nx.draw(graph2, pos=pos, with_labels=True, k=13.8, node_color='lightgreen', node_size=800)
```

[image]

We could generate the intersection of both graphs with `nx.intersection`. This does require that the node sets from both graphs are the same. Also the intersecting nodes will not be removed. In order to do so you can obtain the isolated nodes with [`nx.isolates`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.isolate.isolates.html) and remove them from the graph:

```
g_int = nx.intersection(graph1, graph2)
g_int.remove_nodes_from(list(nx.isolates(g_int)))

pos = nx.spring_layout(g_int, scale=20, k=3/np.sqrt(g_int.order()))
nx.draw(g_int, pos=pos, with_labels=True, k=13.8, node_color='lightgreen', node_size=800)
```

[image]

We could quite easily check that this is indeed the intersection of the edges of both graphs:

```
set_int = set(graph2.edges()).intersection(graph1.edges())
G_set_int = nx.from_edgelist(set_int)
list(nx.connected_components(G_set_int))
# [{1, 2, 3, 4, 6}, {48, 50}, {8, 9, 10, 72}, {76, 78}, {85, 87}, {53, 54}, 
#  {40, 38}, {28, 30}, {20, 21}]
```

Comment: Thank you) This is what me need!